# SQL Server query oo MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I need following SQL Server query to work with MS Access.

```
select (left(x, Charindex('.', x, 1) - 1))As 'CRT', 
        Cast(ROUND((ABS(x) - FLOOR(ABS(x)))* cf,1) as float) As 'PCs'
from (
    select 36 * 1.0 / 36 as x, 36 as cf
) t
```

Comment: If you query the mssql server, you can use a passthrough query, whithout changes.

Comment: I m not directly querying the access, an addon will use it.

Comment: Is the data on `Ms-Access` database and has formerly been on `Ms-Sql` server? Then why did you downgrade? What addon (update question with the addional information)?

Comment: Actually there is a software that have the db in access, i have to get what this query results, same in access.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT Fix(x) AS CRT, CDbl(ROUND((CDbl(x) - Fix(x)) * cf,1)) AS PCs
FROM (
    SELECT 36 * 1.0 / 36 as x, 36 as cf 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    )  AS t;
```

You need a table (myTable) with one row.

Comment: Can you explan, what it does? I've no guess :) Don't forget to mark as answer, to help others get the information, that this solves your problem.If you have questions, how this works feel free to ask.You can use `InStr`replacing `Charindex` and there are `Floor` implementations for vba, just search, but my approach is less confusing ;)

Comment: Actually your query returned me 2 CRT AND -1 PC for ( SELECT CLng(x) AS CRT, CDbl(ROUND((CDbl(x) - CLng(x)) * cf,1)) AS PCs
FROM (
    SELECT 71 * 1.0 / 36 as x, 36 as cf 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE id = 1 )
    )  AS t; And it was wrong result; it expected to return 1 CRT and 35 PCs.

Comment: I have altered your syntax into: <br> SELECT Left(Round(CDbl(x),2),1) AS CRT, ROUND((ABS(x) - Int(ABS(x)))* cf,1) As PCs
FROM (
    SELECT 107 * 1.0 / 36 as x, 36 as cf 
    FROM tmp 
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    )  AS t; <br> this query revealed required results.

Comment: in first part [ Left(Round(CDbl(x),2),1) AS CRT ], I am not rounding it to real number, and extracting the first value e.g: 1.97, here I am extracting only 1 and in second part I am converting the 0.97 into number of pcs.

Comment: One more thing, how can I paste formatted queries and text here in comments, I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Me, stupid! I was not aware of `CLng`rounding. Just use [Fix](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Int-Fix-Functions-5446da0c-fbdc-425f-a818-7e3153984ff8?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) which I used a few weeks ago in an answer, but haven't remembered. I am still not aware of the values represented by the numbers (e.g.: 36, 36 | 71, 36). StackExchange uses [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). A search for "sql formatter" will show several tools that you can try:

Comment: SELECT Int(Round(CDbl(x),2),1) AS CRT, ROUND((ABS(x) - Int(ABS(x)))* cf,1) As PCs
FROM (
    SELECT 107 * 1.0 / 36 as x, 36 as cf 
    FROM tmp 
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    )  AS t

Comment: I am not satified;) Can x get `<0`? If not `ABS()` is not necessary, elsewhere don't you need `ABS()` in CRT? If you round in CRT, actual result would be 3, I assumed 2 (`x = 2,97222..`)?